# Qt SDK: qhash.h error: C2872: 'uint' : ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, c++11, qt5

I have compiled Qt 5.2.1 from source using the following command and VS2012 64bit compiler:

> configure -prefix c:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\msvc2012_opengl -mp
>   -debug-and-release -opengl desktop -c++11 -opensource -D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -nomake examples -skip qtwebkit-examples && nmake && nmake install

Now in QtEditor when compiling my project with VS2012 compiler I am getting this error in qhash.h:

> C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\msvc2012_opengl\include\QtCore\qhash.h:777: error:
>   C2872: 'uint' : ambiguous symbol

Why am I getting it and how can it be solved?

I am getting it even when compiling just the main.cpp with QApplication only:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  return a.exec();
}
```

**Update:**

I found it.It was [GLM Math](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html) library which typedefs uint.I solved it by using glm:: namespace for each glm type.In fact I wonder why Qt API has not namespaced such generally used definitions.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere in your code. You should bring some.

Comment: multiple headers may have defined uint move all Qt header to the top in your includes

Comment: Hmm,can it be causes by the fact the code was written against 4.8.x SDK?

Comment: Found it,glm math lib has typedef of uint

Answer (score 0):

You are likely having conflicting definitions of that type outside your Qt, e.g. in Qt/C++ and a third-party dependency that you are using.

As a side note, there is no such a thing as `QtEditor`.

Comment: Yeah, I meant Qt Creator ;)